# Unable to get file count for a user in Python script

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I am working on a Python script to get the number of files for a given user in a Linux system. The script prompts the user for their username and password, verifies the password using the /etc/shadow file, and then counts the number of files for that user in their home directory.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import subprocess
import crypt

class UserDao:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def verify_password(self, user, password):
        # Read the shadow file and extract the hashed password for the given user
        with open('/etc/shadow', 'r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            fields = line.strip().split(':')
            if fields[0] == user:
                hashed_password = fields[1]
                break
        else:
            raise ValueError("User not found in shadow file")

        # Verify the password against the hashed password
        if crypt.crypt(password, hashed_password) == hashed_password:
            subprocess.run(['su', user,'-c', 'cd && exec bash'], check=True)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def files_count(self, user):
        cmd = f"find /home/{user} -type f -o -type d | wc -l"
        result = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
        output = result.stdout.strip()
        file_count = int(output) if output else 0
        return file_count


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Prompt the user for their username and password
    user = input('Enter your username: ')
    password = input('Enter your password: ')

    # Create a UserDao object and use it to verify the password and count the number of files
    user_dao = UserDao()
    if user_dao.verify_password(user, password):
        file_count = user_dao.files_count(user)
        print(f"Number of files: {file_count}")
    else:
        print('Incorrect password')
```

When I run this script, I am able to verify the user's password, but the script does not return the  file count. Instead, it always returns the following :

```
dev@DESKTOP-7C5A8KF:~$ python3 zip.py
Enter your username: eve
Enter your password: irc
Password:
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
eve@DESKTOP-7C5A8KF:~$
```

Can someone please suggest a solution for this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not a Linux expert but it seems that `bash` (started as subprocess from the Python script) expected that its standard streams were connected to an interactive terminal but they aren't.